# Is $g$ Riemann integrable on $[0,1]?$ Yes/No

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Define  $g : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$ { g }(x)=\begin{cases} \sin   x \quad \text{if}\quad x \in [0,\frac{1}{4}] \\\cos x \quad \text{if}\quad x \in (\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2}] \\ \tan x \quad \text {if} \quad x \in (\frac{1}{2},1]\end{cases} $$

**My question** : Is $g$  Riemann integrable  on $[0,1]?$

**My attempt** : I think **Yes**

$[0,1] = [0,1/4]\cup[1/4,1/2]\cup [1/2,1]$. Now by using  the Darboux's concept  , i,e if $g$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ iff there exists a partition of $[a,b]$ whose sum of areas under curves = $\sum_1^n M_j \varDelta x_j < \varepsilon$.

By Darboux's idea $g$ is integrable on $[0,1/4],[1/4,1/2]$ and $[1/2,1]$

This implies the existence of partitions $\mathcal P_1, \mathcal P_2$  and $\mathcal P_3$ of each interval such that

$$U(\mathcal P_1, g)-L (\mathcal P_1, g)< \epsilon$$

$$U(\mathcal P_2, g)-L (\mathcal P_2, g)< \epsilon$$

and $$U(\mathcal P_3, g)-L (\mathcal P_3, g)< \epsilon$$

Also, $\mathcal{P}=\mathcal P_1 \cup \mathcal P_2 \cup \mathcal P_3$

$$\implies  U(\mathcal P, g)-L (\mathcal P, g)< \epsilon$$

Therefore $g$ is Riemann integrable  on $[0,1]$

Is it true ?

Comment: The function is piecewise Riemann-integrable and therefore Riemann-integrable.

Comment: Seems correct. Although you could have directly used that functions with finite number of discontinuities are Riemann integrable (on compact intervals).

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh: One needs *bounded functions.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani I think my function is bounded because  $f[0,1] \subseteq [0,1]$

Comment: $\tan(1)$ is not ${}\le 1$.

Comment: @GEdgar im not getting .$\tan1=\frac{\sin 1}{\cos 1} \le 1$ since both $\sin 1 \le 1$ and $\cos 1 \le 1$

Comment: You are not getting it.  Note $\frac{2/7}{1/7} = 2$ even though $2/7 < 1$ and $1/7 < 1$.

Comment: @jasmine: Yes, your function is bounded because your interval is "away" from the "poles" of $\tan$. (Although your bounds are incorrect, as pointed out. Note that $\lvert\tan\rvert$ goes to $\infty$ near $\pi/2$, so your logic of both the numerator and denominator being less than $1$ does not hold.)